# Enforce Casbin policy into SQL WHERE

Tags: postgresql, go, abac, casbin

I have trouble implementing ABAC with Postgresql. My plan is to use Cabsin but I can't figure out how translate Cabsin security clauses into SQL WHERE predicates.

Comment: See scaling ABAC: https://casbin.org/docs/en/abac#scaling-the-model-for-complex-and-large-number-of-abac-rules

Comment: @YangLuo do you have any reference how one could achieve casbin policy enforsment in SQL like it could be done with OPA - https://blog.openpolicyagent.org/write-policy-in-opa-enforce-policy-in-sql-d9d24db93bf4 with this ABAC scaling?